# Exception cant be casted to HttpException

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

Anyone can explain what can be reasons to when i throw a HttpException, when its bubbled up, cant be casted from Exception.
Giving a bit more context, i have a generic razor view with a try..catch of Exception, that calls children views, and in a children view i have throw HttpException.
The problem is that in generic view the Exception cant be casted to HttpException when its raised.
This only happen in a Test Envoriment, in my local machine this works(as expected).

Code:

Children view:

```
...
 }
    else
    {
        throw new HttpException(400,"Not Found");

    }
```

Generic View

```
try
{
    @Html.CachedPartial(moduleItem.DocumentTypeAlias, moduleItem, 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
                                                                           contextualKeyBuilder: (model, viewData) => { return string.Format("{0}|{1}", moduleItem.Id, Request.QueryString); },
                                                                           viewData: ViewData)
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //the ex.GetType() is Exception when HttpException is raised 
    if (ex != null && ex.GetType()== typeof(HttpException))
    {
        var httpExp = ex as HttpException;
        var code = httpExp.GetHttpCode();
        if (code == 400)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
            var xpathQuery = String.Format("//error404");
            var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
            var contentService = umbracoHelper.TypedContentAtXPath(xpathQuery);
            var culture = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
            var moduleItem404 = contentService.FirstOrDefault(x=> x.GetCulture().TwoLetterISOLanguageName== culture);
            @Html.CachedPartial(moduleItem404.DocumentTypeAlias, moduleItem404, 60 * 60 * 24 * 365,
                                                                           contextualKeyBuilder: (model, viewData) => { return string.Format("{0}|{1}", moduleItem404.Id, Request.QueryString); },
                                           viewData: ViewData)
}
else
{
    throw ex;
}
}
else
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Any ideas, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to catch different types of exceptions

```
try {
// code
}
catch (HttpException ex){
// code
}
catch (Exception ex){
// code
}
```

Comment: Hi Artur, i know, the problem is that the catch(HttpException) is not catched, the HttpException is catched as Exception....

Comment: @RuiEstreito Maybe it's throwing other type of exception. Could you check it in debugger?

Comment: I already had checked, and all Exception propreties are null, i cant debug because the problem its in Staging envoriment, on my local machine work correctly, if i thow a different Exception the problem is the same.